# I created 2 functions to same view in same controller but last route's function only working

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I created 2 functions to same view in same controller but last one only working

This is my function

```
class ProspectController extends Controller {

    public function get_prospects() {
        $prospects = DB::select('select * from prospect');
        return view('prospect', ['prospects' => $prospects]);
    }

    public function get_courses() {
        $courses = DB::select('select * from course');
        return view('prospect', ['courses' => $courses]);
    }

}
```

This is my route

```
Route::get('prospect', 'ProspectController@get_courses');
Route::get('prospect', 'ProspectController@get_prospects');
```

This is my view file

```
@foreach($courses as $course)

      <input type="checkbox" id="{{$course->course_id}}" 
      name="course_intrested[]" value="{{$course- >course_name}}">
      <label for="defaultCheck">{{$course-  >course_name}}</label>

@endforeach
```

But i'm getting this error

```
 Undefined variable:
 courses (View:C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\customer_inquiry_model\resources\
 views\prospect.blade.php)
```

But course function working when I change route like this

```
 Route::get('prospect', 'ProspectController@get_prospects');
 Route::get('prospect', 'ProspectController@get_courses');
```

but first one is not working. This is my problem.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using **duplicate** routes. Therefore **only the last route** is being used.

And in the first case, you pass `prospects` variable and try to use `courses` so it throws an error.

```
public function get_prospects() {
    $prospects = DB::select('select * from prospect');
    return view('prospect', ['prospects' => $prospects]); // <---- 'prospects' should be 'courses'

}
```

But even if you change variable name, your logic still remains wrong. You need to set **two different** routes (and most probably two different template files) Like following:

```
Route::get('courses', 'ProspectController@get_courses');
Route::get('prospect', 'ProspectController@get_prospects');
```

**UPDATE**

As you mentioned in the comment, if you would like to pass courses and prospects to the same view you can do the following:

```
public function get_prospects() {
    $prospects = DB::select('select * from prospect');
    $courses = DB::select('select * from course');
    return view('prospect', ['prospects' => $prospects, 'courses' => $courses]);

}
```

And you need to remove the second route and leave it as following:

```
Route::get('prospect', 'ProspectController@get_prospects');
```

Comment: but i need to retrieve courses and prospect to same 'prospect' view